# Solr throwing error org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Attempted an atomic/partial update to a child doc without indicating the _root_ somehow

Tags: solr

We seem to get this error with an existing record in Solr

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Attempted an atomic/partial update to a child doc without indicating the _root_ somehow.
```

If I change the reference id to something that doesn't exist; it adds it fine and I can happily fire the same request in with no issue. I don't really understand this message and reading the solr documentation that also doesn't make sense!

Should it not just replace the whole document, thought it would be as simple as that, is the record corrupts maybe!?

How might I debug the issue in Solr or know what to look for?

Our **solrconfig.xml** had these defaults in, but unsure if this is what can cause this error.

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" default="${update.autoCreateFields:true}" processor="uuid,remove-blank,field-name-mutating,parse-boolean,parse-long,parse-double,parse-date,add-schema-fields">
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

The url we seem to call is the following with the json object passed in

```
POST /solr/mycore/update?commit=true
```

I think these two links may have relevance, but all rather low level issues.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-15468

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-14923

We don't store child objects, we only store single values or arrays of strings/numbers. We do also store the original JSON object string in the **Bookings** field, which has lots of extra stuff that we stripped out, this is a **text_en** field, so wondering if that's the issue; presume that is indexed which sounds dodgy as it can be quite a large object.

[image]

Comment: The message makes it look like you are using atomic updates (https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_4/updating-parts-of-documents.html) rather than trying to replace the entire document. How does your request to Solr looks like?

Comment: Hi @HectorCorrea, is there a way to turn off atomic updates as reading the page it seems like its just there by default?

Comment: I think atomic updates kick in as soon as you pass `set`, `add`, `remove` as part of the body of the payload in the POST request. What does the payload looks like in your case?

Comment: Ok, we dont use set, add or remove; we just send the json document. It sounds like it might be old data as we can make the same call with the same json just different id and it works. which is strange. I provided 2 links above, that seem to point to the _root_ issue. We are using solr 8.11.1 moving from 7.6. I cant provide to much of an example as it contains personal data. We don't store child objects, only array string/numbers of single values. The Booking one could be the issue as shown in the update above as its a text_en field!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current approach was to delete the record via the cores Document tab, then we could submit the request with no problems!

[image]

I do wonder if the issue stems from increasing a version from 7.6 to 8.11.1, but the person who copied the data just copied the data folder from 7.6 and put it in the 8.11.1 version, this seems rather dodgy and imagine a backup may have been a better idea.